# Calculating $ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} (x^2+2y^2)^{2x-y} $ if it exists

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

> Calculate  $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)} (x^2+2y^2)^{2x-y} $ if it exists.

I tried to show that this limit does not exist. But I can't find two different numerical sequences that give two different limits.

Maybe that limit exists, but I do not know how to find it.

I will be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Hint: write this as $\exp((2x-y) \log(x^2+ 2 y^2))$, then use that $|x| \le \sqrt{x^2 + 2y^2}$ and a similar relation for $|y|$.

Comment: Could you please give me hint where I should use these $|x| \leq \sqrt{x^2+2y^2}$ relations?

Comment: Try to bound $|(2x-y) \log(x^2 + 2 y^2)|$ from above.